# which one would you say, I've passed my probation or employer extended?

Tags: recruitment, contracts, hiring, probation

Today it's been 3 months since I've started working for my company. Couple weeks ago I got a letter my salary will increase from July. And a few days ago I've been asked to take part in recruitment process and my work email has been added to indeed and I keep getting CVs from applicants. How do I know if I've passed my probation or it's been extended if nobody tells me anything?

Comment: You know when you're still employed after the probationary period.

Comment: What does your contract say about your probation period? Does it say anything about automatically extending by another period of time under certain circumstances?

Comment: If nobody is telling you if you passed your probationary period, you should ask whomever, is making that determination if that has happened or not.

Answer (score 5):

> How do I know if I've passed my probation or it's been extended if nobody tells me anything?

Ask your manager or HR. You can call them or email them.

Comment: I live in the UK

Comment: Do they have neither phones or email in the UK?

Answer (score 0):

Usually contracts are worded such that that your probation ends after the agreed period. So they will say something like:

> For your first six months you will be on probation and during that time can be terminated with no notice.

If that's the case then, assuming nobody has told you different, you are no longer on probation after six months. You've "passed" it by not being fired in your first six months or specifically being told it's been extended.

Contracts can be worded differently, so read yours to see what it says. And definitely **ask your boss or HR** to confirm this.

Most companies are pretty lax about informing a person they have "passed" probation. I've rarely been told that my probation has ended, and when I have it's been pretty much in passing.

Answer (score -1):

Without know your location, it's a bit hard to say - but *generally* - where countries have a probationary period, that's normally accompanied by a slightly lower rate. The salary increase would tend to suggest you have passed your probationary period (although when NZ had a 90 day trial, the salary increase would coincide with the end of the probation period).

The best solution here is to contact whoever your management is, via email and get confirmation in writing.

Comment: As far as I know, they always increase salary after 6 months working in the business. But when I had my interview I've been told the probationary period is 12 weeks.

Comment: @Iga - Have you asked somebody in your HR department these questions?